# React Native changing background color according to data that comes through http request from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new at React Native.

I'm working on a code that will change the background color of a box (card) according to the data that I will get from API. I want to check first if the title is like 'Taylor' make background red , if it is 'Fearless' make it green and so on.

Here is the API that I got information from :

http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums

This is the code divided into several files.

First of them index.js

```
// Import a library to help to create a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header.js';
import AlbumList from './src/components/AlbumList.js'

// create a component
const App = () => (
  <View>
      <Header headerText={'Smart Parking'}/>
      <AlbumList />
  </View>
);


//render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums2', () => App);
```

second is AlbumList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail.js'

class AlbumList extends Component {
  state = { albums: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
       .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }) );
  }

renderAlbums() {
  return this.state.albums.map(album =>
     <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album} />
   );
}

  render() {
     return(
       <View>
          {this.renderAlbums()}
       </View>
     );
  }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

3rd is AlbumDetail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card.js'

const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
  return(
     <Card>
        <Text> {props.album.title} </Text>
     </Card>
  );
};

export default AlbumDetail;
```

4th is card which I need to change background of it

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
     <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        {props.children}
     </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height:2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10
  }
};

export default Card;
```

last one is header

```
// Import libraries for making components
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

// make a components
const Header = (props) => {
   const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
   return(
     <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
     </View>
   )
};
const styles ={
   viewStyle:{
     backgroundColor:'orange',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     height: 60,
   },
   textStyle: {
     fontSize: 20
   }
};
// make the component to the other part of the app
export default Header;
```

Comment: In your `AlbumDetail` check the title, and then pass a new color to the card.

Comment: can you write this in details please ?  and this what iam going to write inside albumdetail , should it be out of return ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to pass the title of the album as prop to the Card from the AlbumDetails component and then on each Card calculate the color to use and pass it in the style like this:

```
// AlbumDetails.js component
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card.js'

const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
  return(
     <Card title={props.album.title}>
        <Text> {props.album.title} </Text>
     </Card>
  );
};

export default AlbumDetail;

// Card.js component
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

function calculateColor(title) {
  let bgColor;

  switch (title) {
    case "Taylor":
      bgColor = "red";
      break;
    case "Fearless":
      bgColor = "green";
      break;
    default:
      bgColor = "orange";
      break;
  }

  return bgColor;
}

const Card = props => {
  const { title } = props;
  const backgroundColor = calculateColor(title);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10
  }
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: function calculatecolor , where will be written , and what will i write at AlbumDetail's return ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

**Change the `AlbumDetail` to conditionally render the `Card`.**

```
const AlbumDetail = props => {
  if (props.album.title === 'Taylor') {
    return (
      <Card style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
      </Card>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Card style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
      </Card>
    );
  } 
};
```

**Override the default style of the card using the passed `style` prop.**

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]}>{props.children}</View>
  );
};
```

Comment: error appeared at android emulator says : invariant violation :AlbumDetail :nothing was returned from render, this usually means a return statement is missing or to render nothing, return null.

Comment: I've updated the code. You can change it to add more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

accepted answer is great just its a bad habit to do things in render.

i also not sure since every title has a color why wouldnt the server send this in the object props in first place ? :)

```
class AlbumList extends Component {
  state = { albums: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
       .then(response=> Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : []) // alittle validation would not hurt :) ! 
       .then(data => this.setState({ albums: data }) );
  }
  selectHeaderColorForAlbum( album ){
    let headerColor = 'red';
    // switch(album.title){ ..you logic }
    return headerColor;
  }
renderAlbums() {
  return this.state.albums.map(album =>
     <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album} color={this.selectHeaderColorForAlbum(album)} />
   );
}

  render() {
     return(
       <View>
          {this.renderAlbums()}
       </View>
     );
  }
}

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
     <View style={[styles.containerStyle,{color:props.headerColor}]}>
        {props.children}
     </View>
  );
};
```

this is easier your logic will render only once.

- also notice that react >16.0 depricated `componentWillMount`, so use `DidMount`